# how to login in magento admin using coding

Tags: magento-1.7

Hi magento geeks i need your help, 
i'm adding product from backend code in my magneto server, i want to set admin session when product creating then only it will we shown in both front and back end now its working fine for setting admin session id manually.

now i want to set admin session according to admin login based,  of-course i will give admin username and password since i will get current logged in user id.

what i want is login magento admin using coding.
any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found solution for this question

```
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));

    // supply username
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername('Admin_name_to_login'); // user your admin username

    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
      Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->renewSecretUrls();
    }

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $session->setIsFirstVisit(true);
    $session->setUser($user);
    $session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
    Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success',array('user'=>$user));

    if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
      echo "Logged in";
    }
    else{
        echo 'Not Logged';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, had to use it to trick MageWorx Customer Credit module to let me import data programmatically.  Just make sure 'adminhtml' is a valid Magento admin user name.  Thanks sudhakar.